# Can I call $.ajax method inside $.getJson()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, getjson

I want to insert value into database and with $.getJson() method I check if my value exist into database and if not I want to call $.ajax to put it into database I tried like this and modal dialog pops up but method continue with execution and I my application is broken every time how to prevent execution after modal dialog pops up I try to put $.ajax inside else block but nothing then I tried like this but nothing?

```
enter $("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).closest("#forma1");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr("Create"),

        data:   $.getJSON("/InspekcijskeKontrole/Check?id1=" + $("#kombo3").val() + "&id2=" + $("#kombo4").val(), function (data) {

            if (data.InspekcijskoTijeloId != -1 && data.ProizvodId != -1) {
                $.getJSON("/Proizvodi/VratiIme/" + data.ProizvodId, function (ime) {

                    if (ime != null) {
                        $("#modalni1 p").text("Inspekcijska kontrola za " + ime + " je vec izvrsena");
                        $("#modalni1").modal({ backdrop: "static" });

                    }
                });

            } 

        }),
        data:form.serialize(),

        success: function (response) {

         alert("Informacije su uspjesno ubacene");
         window.location.href = "/InspekcijskeKontrole/Index";


        },
        error: function (greska) {
            alert("Doslo je do greske pri ubacivanju");
        }

    });

});code here
```

Comment: but why are you using two `getJSON` requestes?

Comment: One to check if object exist and one to get the name of object if exist for showing information on modal dialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the two inner "Check" and "VratiMe" ajax calls finish *after* the post has already completed.

Because they are Asynchronous (ie queue up and return immediately and then complete at a later date).

You should be able to change the order of your calls to something like:

```
var form = $(this).closest("#forma1");

$.getJSON("/InspekcijskeKontrole/Check?id1=" + $("#kombo3").val() + "&id2=" + $("#kombo4").val(), function (data) {

    if (data.InspekcijskoTijeloId != -1 && data.ProizvodId != -1) {
        $.getJSON("/Proizvodi/VratiIme/" + data.ProizvodId, function (ime) {

            if (ime != null) {
                $("#modalni1 p").text("Inspekcijska kontrola za " + ime + " je vec izvrsena");
                $("#modalni1").modal({ backdrop: "static" });
            }
        });
    }
    else {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("Create"),

            data:form.serialize(),

            success: function (response) {

             alert("Informacije su uspjesno ubacene");
             window.location.href = "/InspekcijskeKontrole/Index";


            },
            error: function (greska) {
                alert("Doslo je do greske pri ubacivanju");
            }

        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: I tried like this but nothing works I am stucked for a long time then I got error for __RequstVerificationToken is not present but token is include inside serialize();

Comment: Made an update and moved the else based on your additional details in the question and comments

Comment: So the question is:  Does your form submit *without* the check calls?  Sounds like it doesn't, which is a completely different problem and nothing to do with ajax calls.

Comment: Hey man it works now like this but I tried I swear on this way now it works ?

Comment: Error was because `var form=$(this).closest("form");` I called in ajax method

Comment: Yes, `this` changes a lot, depending on the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the check and possible insert in one request? I would strongly prefer to do it in one request!

But okay, that wasn't the question. To use the result of `$.getJSON` in `$.ajax` put it in the success callback of `$.getJSON`. Like this:

```
$.getJSON("getJsonUrl.html", function(responseOne) {
    $.getJSON("anotherJsonRequest.html", function(responseTwo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxUrl.html",
            type: "POST",
            data = responseTwo
        });
    });
});
```